# Mootools 1.3.1: Selector for parent (id) > child

Tags: javascript, mootools, css-selectors

I am currently working on a mootools 1.3.1 script and have a structure like this:

```
<div id="100">
<img src="">
</div>
```

I know already the selector `$$('div.class img')` but how does it look for an id?

The whole documentation for css selectors on mootools.net is missing: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Selectors

And here is only for class?: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Slick/Slick

Comment: Just a note, as i think this is not real code: ids can't start with numbers

Comment: but it throws no error, theoretically it can and practically too but where does it fail then?

Comment: Three things: 1) IDs *can* start with numbers in HTML5. 2) This is HTML, not XML, so browsers don't need to throw errors on invalid IDs; they can just handle it however they like even though it's not conformant. 3) That said, just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*. If you knowingly write markup that causes invalid or unspecified behavior, it's up to you to cater to whatever a browser feels like doing with the invalid markup.

Comment: why didnt they make it earlier or conform? really annoying if you forget this little but important fact.

Comment: For the record, your question title contradicts your question body. Do you want `parent > child` only, or `element descendant`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the class selector with an ID selector?

```
$$('div#100 img')
```

If you only want `img` elements that are children of `div#100`, add a child combinator as in your question title:

```
$$('div#100 > img')
```

If MooTools says it supports CSS selectors, it shouldn't be that much of a difference from the standard CSS that we use. If the latest documentation is somehow missing, it should still be sufficient to fall back to a previous but still recent version (here's the documentation for [MooTools 1.2.5](http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Utilities/Selectors), the second Google result for "mootools selectors") or regular CSS documentation, like the [W3C selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors).

Comment: OK, so 1.2.5 is actually a really old version, but it should suffice for simple cases like this.